# Why 'dokku plugins-install' doesn't work as expected?

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm trying to use simple `dokku plugins-install` command, but my system replies me with:

> `plugins-install` is not a dokku command.
>
> See `dokku help` for a list of available commands.

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is only a command on the 0.3.x line. The latest line or releases, 0.4.x. You can see how to install a plugin [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/plugins/#installing-a-plugin)